# -bash: python: command not found on mac

Tags: python, macos

I've tried a number of approaches:

```
brew install python
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: python@3.11 3.11.2_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.11.2_1, run:
  brew reinstall python@3.11
williamm-5541:~ williamm$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

and

```
williamm-5541:git williamm$ pyenv version
3.11.2 (set by /Users/williamm/.pyenv/version)
williamm-5541:git williamm$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

The command `python3` works however python does not which is blocking me from installing:

https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup

Comment: You could just create a syslink from python3 binary to python

Comment: But most of the times, cli tooling allow you to specify the python path, aws tooling should probably have that, take a look at the docs

Comment: Also note that the symlink @0stone0 mentions would generally be created automatically if you use a virtual environment as recommended in that guide.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `python3` instead of `python` in those installation instructions?

Comment: I have @jasonharper and it returns:
`eb help
env: python: No such file or directory`

Comment: alias didn't work, also sys link might torch the system python that mac os needs. I tried installing in venv and got `(py3venv) williamm-5541:git williamm$ python ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/ebcli_installer.py
ERROR: This script cannot be executed inside a virtual environment.`

Comment: @0stone0 the command still requires me to have a working python command

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

This worked

Comment: The `python` name is historically used to get a Python 2.x interpreter. Software depending on that historical interpretation may be surprised.

Comment: I know  good call out but this was blocking a release to prod, I hate this python vs python3 bs on mac